# почему аудио загружется заново?

Tags: javascript, аудио

пытаюсь сделать плеер и когда включаю песню audio.load() audio.play() начинается загрузка и потом через несколько секунд включается, если остановить песню audio.pause() и потом включить опять, то приходится ожидать опять, хотя до этого загрузка была. если убрать audio.load() то песня вообще не включается

Comment: Получайте, добавляйте на страницу файлы закодированные в base64-url

Comment: а зачем второй раз load запускать?